# error with tfs api method VersionControlServer.GetItems

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item In Me.VersionControlServer.GetItems("$/TeamProject/Product/Website/*.*", Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType.Full).Items
```

I am having an inconsistent error and issue I can't seem to reproduce when calling GetItems for tfs api versioncontrol.  99% of the time it works fine.  And then infrequently it will crash and I get some xml unexpected token error.  Sometimes run this process again and it works.  I am not sure how to track this down.

Ideas?

Comment: When you say "crash" you mean fail with an exception about xml parsing?  *99%* time I have seen this it's an HTTP proxy mangling your response.  The remaining 1% is a server failure throwing a `500` for some other crazy reason.  Can you post the exception?  Can you show the server logs for this request?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes. crash with an error about xml parsing.  I didn't think about a proxy.  I'm in the process of adding additional exception handling because my initial global exception handling was not properly looping through to get inner exceptions.  And this issue is not happening on any consistent basis

Comment: Cool - if you can get some additional details, like what the response actually looks like, it would help track this down.